# Configuring SQL server 2005 enterprise edition

Tags: sql-server-2005

What are the basic settings required for running SQL server 2005 enterprise edition in a local computer.
When i take program from start menu it shows only sql server configuration manager, surface area manager, error reporting and a command prompt. There is no SQL server launching shortcut. How i get it?

Comment: I suppose the other authors already answered your question. I just wonder why to install Enterprice on local computer, if Developer Edition has all features of Enterprise and the license cost is significantly lower ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think SQL Server already runs on your machine. What do you mean of "SQL Server launching shortcut"? There is no such standalone thing. SQL Server components run as services. Check for them running using Start -> Run -> services.msc.

If you mean some GUI for managing the server, it is called SQL Server Management Studio, it can usually be found on the second disk, if you used CDs for installation. Try to reinstall the server and don't forget to check Management Studio while installation (it can be found under some other node, like 'User tools' or something, I don't remember for sure now).

Answer (score 1):

My recollection of the SQL Server installation is that it's irritatingly easy to not install the SQL Server Management Studio. It's an option that isn't ticked by default.

On my system the shortcut  for Management Studio points to "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWb.exe" so you can easily see if it's installed.

JR